# How to pass value from rax to xmm register

Tags: assembly, sse

I want to pass value from `%rax` or memory to `%xmm0` and this value shoud be of double, so i can later multiply `%xmm0` by sth.

Currently im using this:

```
movq    $1, -72(%rbp)
movq    -72(%rbp), %rax
movsd   -72(%rbp), %xmm0  # 1 should be
movsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm1   # 5
mulss   %xmm0, %xmm1      # 5 shoud be
```

But under %mm0(double) I got 0, not 1. When I multiply it's returning 0... :(

```
xmm0           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0}, 
  v16_int8 = {0x1, 0x0 <repeats 15 times>}, 
  v8_int16 = {0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
  v4_int32 = {0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
  v2_int64 = {0x1, 0x0}, 
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000001
}
```

Any ideas how to pass integer to xmm0? Or how to multiply/divide xmm1 by -72(%rbp) so return would be correct?

AT&T, linux, 64b.

EDIT: I read sth about PINSRW but dont know how to use it.

Comment: You either have to load a floating point value from memory, or convert from an integer, e.g., `movl $1, mem; cvtsi2sd mem, %xmm0`

Comment: Why u didn't posted this as an answer? It works btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Presumed) Problem:**

`movq $1, -72(%rbp)` moves the integer value 1 into memory, which, when represented as a floating point number is something extremely small. When you multiply 'x' by this number the result is so small that it's rounded to 0.

**Potential Solutions:**

- Move a floating point immediate value of 1.0f into memory, instead of 1. I can't say exactly how to do this because I don't know what assembler you're using.
- Like Brett Hale said, convert the integer into a floating point number. There's probably a million ways to do this, so just Google something like "SSE Integer to Float", and you'll a bunch of results.

Comment: As you say, simply interpreting 64-bit integral values of (1) or (5) as 'doubles' yields extremely small (and de-normalized) IEEE-754 values. As doubles: `(0x1) ~ 4.94E-324`, and `(0x5) ~ 2.47E-323`.

Comment: Oh, I googled, like for 2 hours, but most of solutions are for Intel assembly, which is confusing to me. Im using also Intel instructions set reference, and I need to waste a lot of time to figure out where goes what in AT&T. fml. Also probably I was asking google wrong question...

Comment: @Kmaczek Did you find a solution? If not I could probably come up with something for you.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 Yes I found it. There are many ways to do this actualy.